# Quisiera hacer que se cree el archivo con los datos que se encuentren en el formulario

Tags: php, html

El formulario es algo simple como

```
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="creador.php" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="datos" id="datos" />
        <input type="submit" name="formSubmit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
</body>
```

y el script php es tambien simple

```
$datos1=_POST("datos");

$html= aquí va la página web y en mitad de código me gustaría meter el datos1

file_put_contents('C:\xampp\htdocs\prueba2\Pagfinal.html', $html);
```

Comment: Hola Guillermo bienvenido. Quieres que los datos de los campos se guarden en un fichero? Txt, csv, doc ..?

Comment: En un documento html pero cuando lo ejecuto sólo me muestra la página web y donde iría datos1 solo me sale como $datos1

Comment: Es decir, que no es necesario grabar a un archivo, que sólo te interesa que luego de hacer click en `Submit`, el texto que el usuario escribió en el `<input>` se muestre dentro de la nueva página???

Comment: Justamente eso.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sacado de [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15236785/3045491) te muestra como preparar la pagina `creador.php` para que reciba la variable con nombre `datos`.

**index.php**

```
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="creador.php" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="datos" id="datos" />
        <input type="submit" name="formSubmit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
</body>
```

**creador.php**

```
 <html>
 <body>

<script type="text/javascript">  

  var datos ="<?php echo $_POST['datos']; ?>";
  var ventanaHTML = window.open("about:blank", "_blank");

  ventanaHTML.document.writeln("hola! tus datos: " + datos);

</script>

 </body>
 </html>
```

**output**

Hola! tus datos  _____ !

Comment: Vale, muchisimas gracias. No sabes el problema que me has resuelto.